# How do I create a column for json_table that stores more than 32767 bytes?

Tags: oracle

I am mapping json to table in oracle using json_table. I want to store one of the fields (excel_data) in a column of type clob as the size of that field goes beyond 32767. However, json_table does not seem to accept clob. How do I solve this? I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production. is there any other way except updating the version?

```
  SELECT
        version,
        excel_data
    INTO
        m_version,
        m_excel_data
    FROM
        dual,
        JSON_TABLE ( data, '$'
                COLUMNS (
                   version VARCHAR2 ( 200 ) PATH '$.version',
                    excel_data VARCHAR2 ( 32000 ) PATH '$.excel_data'                )
            );
```

Comment: I wish people on stackoverflow, including you, realized that we need to know what version of the Oracle Database you are using. The answer to your question lies in the version.

Comment: 19c docs shows that CLOB is a valid input for path expression ... https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62  " If expr is a column, then the column must be of data type VARCHAR2, CLOB, or BLOB. If expr is null, then the function returns null."

Comment: 12c isn't descriptive enough, are you on 12.1 or 12.2 - there are HUGE differences in terms of JSON functionality